# How can I reduce the response buffer size of the reverse proxy?

Tags: iis-7, rewrite, throttling

I have configured some reverse proxies in order to map some HTTP audio streams that are normally accessed via different port numbers (e.g. `http://fooserver:18030`), to URL addresses accessible on standard port 80 (e.g. `http://fooserver/capitalRadio`).

It is working fine, but I have a problem. It seems there is some heavy buffering being done on the server.  It takes around 5 minutes for the stream to start playing on the client.

Having no prior experience with URL rewriting on IIS, can someone point me out which setting(s) I can throttle back to reduce the playing delay?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

dont have a machine running IIS ARR infront of me at the moment, but found the following:

Server Farms > FarmName > Proxy > Buffer section > Response Buffer Threshold

Via [here](http://forums.iis.net/t/1179161.aspx). Hope this helps...

Comment: @TiermanO, thanks for responding.  When I set up the reverse proxy, I did it at the directory level  (I created a normal directory under ´inetpub/wwwroot´  and then added a ´web.config´ file with the URL Rewrite rule), unfortunately I don't have anything under Server Farms (the list is empty)  Do you recommend that I create one even though just a single server will be responding to client requests? Thanks again.

Comment: I think arr is the newer version of redirection... It has some extra features... It maybe your best bet to install and confirm that... Even if you only have a single box...

Comment: @TiermanO, thank you, it was not necessary to create a Server Farm, the `Application Request Routing` feature has a `Server Proxy Settings` section with  `Response buffer size` and `Response buffer threshold` settings. I set the values to 256 and 8 KB respectively and it solved the problem.  I'm not allowed yet to grant you the bounty, I must wait 13 hours more, but thanks for pointing me to the solution.

Comment: No problem. Glad to help!